# when i write: '\'\\\'\'' why do i get different results in FireFox and Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, undefined-behavior

When I write

```js
'\'\\\'\''
```

Why do I get different results in Firefox and Chrome? is that code invoking

> JavaScript undefined behaviour

or something? in Chrome I get (as I kindof expected)

```
'\''
```

but in Firefox I get:

```
'\\''
```

Comment: That seems to be a difference in representing strings in the console. The actual string is the same in both browsers, though. For example, compare the evaluation of `"\\"[0]`.